# Can't figure out what's using my Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, truecrypt

So I'm trying to Encrypt one of my Hard Drives using TrueCrypt.

It says it's in use of by either the operating system or an application, but I cannot figure out what's using my Hard Drive.

I am using Windows 8, and it's not my Boot Drive. I actually have 2 of the same Hard Drives, and one of them I encrypted just fine.

It's very strange since the one I'm trying to encrypt is used the least out of all of them.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Tried turning off the Indexing service temporarily?

Comment: @Karan, This is a good question.  Id bump it up even further and ask how long you have had Windows 8 installed?  Is the drive full of data or a blank, freshly formatted drive?  Have you tried unmounting it manually? (i.e, running a chkdsk /r on the drive will force windows to ask if you want to unmount it...)

Comment: @Karan Just tried that, didn't work. And francisswest, it contains data, it's not empty.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) from Microsoft, there's an application called procmon.exe that you can use and try to isolate the application. Try killing off most  applications first to avoid interference.

Answer (score 2):

The most powerful tool I've found is Unlocker: http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/.

Right-click the drive and select Unlocker, and it will show you what process is using it, and give you hard core options to powerfully force those processes to release their locks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try booting into safe mode first?

http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/

I know this might be an obvious answer, but you never know when there could be that random driver trying to access hard drives.